# Can you trigger a Jenkins job via SMS message?

Tags: jenkins, sms

Is there a way to trigger a Jenkins build by simply sending a text message?

Comment: Sure, but you need some code in between that triggers a call e.g. to the REST API of Jenkins upon reception of an SMS.. This is not such well-suited question for StackOverflow.